# jQuery return true if multiple selectors are disabled

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I'm working on a form where all fields are disabled except "textarea".
When the user types anything into textarea and all inputs are disabled, the button "valid" will be enabled.
I tried it with single selector and it worked but with multiple selectors it doesn't work.

HTML (one input field is left enabled intentionally to restrict button from enabling)

```
<div id="inputs">
    <input type="file" name="first" id="first" class="upload_file"/>
    <input type="file" name="second" id="second" class="upload_file" disabled/>
    <input type="file" name="third" id="third" class="upload_file" disabled/>
    <textarea name="response" id="response"></textarea> <br/>
</div>

<div id="button">
    <button id="valid" disabled>Valid</button>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#response').on('keyup', function(e) {
    // if response is not set return false
    if ($("#response").length && !$.trim($("#response").val())){
        $('#valid').attr('disabled', true)
    }else {
        // if response is set and inputs are not disabled, return true
        if($('#first, #second, #third').is(':disabled')){
            $('#valid').attr('disabled', false)
        }
    }
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xiarahman/o5xzs9d4/9/)

Comment: Hello. Each input has the same identifier for you, and this is not correct. The id must be unique for each element.

Comment: Yes segey. I had to re formulate the code for easier record and forgot the change the copied inputs. Fiddle and Code both edited, yet the issue prevails.

Comment: whats your expected output i am not sure what you are trying to do with those two disabled inputs ?

Comment: I want the button to stay disabled if user types anything into textarea when any of the input is not disabled.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I replied to your answer :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need to count the inputs of class `.upload_file` which are enabled. If that number is 0 (and the text field has some contenti in it, of course) then you can enable your input. Something like here below

```
$('#response').on('keyup', function(e) {
// if response is not set return false
    if ($("#response").length && !$.trim($("#response").val())){
        $('#valid').attr('disabled', true)
    }else {
  // if response is set and inputs are not disabled, return true
        if( $(".upload_file:enabled").length==0){
            $('#valid').attr('disabled', false)
        }
    }
});
```